# Facebook Graph API: Work history

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

How to get friend's work history using Facebook Graph API version 2.8 and above?

```
me/friends?fields=id,name,birthday,work
```

If I send this, I am not getting friend's work history. These permissions are mapped as deprecated in facebook doc.

> user_work_history
>
> This permission was deprecated on April 4, 2018.

Is there any alternate for this?

EDIT: As mentioned in comment(@luschn), https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes link clearly says all these info are not available from yesterday!.

Comment: If they wanted you to still be able to get this data, they would probably not have removed this permission in the first place ...

Comment: Ok, But Facebook did not clearly mention in any document saying these fields are no longer available. How can they suddenly stop supporting something.

Comment: They simply are in a “panic mode” right now, trying to fix their issues (although I am not too sure that’s possible, if they want to keep their current business model at the same time) - and while that might “hurt” some genuine developers at this point, protecting user data is the first priority right now. This is not saying that access to some of the currently limited data might not come back at some point and in some form, but for now you really just need to let them figure this out first.

Comment: "Facebook did not clearly mention in any document saying these fields are no longer available" - actually, they did: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes

Comment: @luschn Thanks for letting me know. I could not locate this page. So it is officially closed. !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes

The breaking changes from April 4, 2018 state that the field is deprecated and will not be usable anymore. There is no workaround.